# R subsetting and factor levels

Tags: r, dataset, subset

I was wondering why it is that when subsetting a dataframe, the new frame retains the factor levels of the parent dataframe.  For example, consider an arcaheological data set that includes non-technological materials that are not germane to the analysis.  The data frame contains "provenance", "depth", "size class", "artifact type" and "material" (e.g. andesite, basalt, obsidian, etc.).  Effectively all of these variables are factors.  As a first step extracting a subset of only those records that contain identified artifacts seems reasonable.

> nd <- subset(od, od$tech != "na")

That step should eliminate a couple of low frequency materials (e.g. andesite) that were properly identified, but were not artifacts.  The records are marked in the "tech" field as "na" - in this case "not artifact."  After the subset is extracted the levels count for "material" should be reduced.  However an xtabs() or table() application reveals that the "levels" of the parent factor ("material") remain active.  Minor workarounds are required to pursuade R to ignore the original factor levels in favour of the shortened list relevant to the new dataframe.

The text below include R commands, str() output, and table() output as an example.

```
m <- c('and', 'bas', 'bas', 'obs', 'bas', 'ccs', 'qzt', 'qzt')
a <- c('na', 'mfp', 'mfp', 'pf', 'na', 'pf', 'pf', 'sh')
t <- data.frame(m, a)

str(t)
  'data.frame': 8 obs. of  2 variables:
  $ m: Factor w/ 5 levels "and","bas","ccs",..: 1 2 2 4 2 3 5 5
      $ a: Factor w/ 4 levels "mfp","na","pf",..: 2 1 1 3 2 3 3 4

table(t)
     a
m     mfp na pf sh
  and   0  1  0  0
  bas   2  1  0  0
  ccs   0  0  1  0
  obs   0  0  1  0
  qzt   0  0  1  1
nt <- subset(t, a != 'na')
```

Note below that the "a" factor reports the same factors after the subset() operation.  Using bracket notation has the same results.

```
str(nt)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ m: Factor w/ 5 levels "and","bas","ccs",..: 2 2 4 3 5 5
     $ a: Factor w/ 4 levels "mfp","na","pf",..: 1 1 3 3 3 4
```

**Note below in table() output that "na" is still present as factor with zero occurrences.**

```
table(nt)

     a
m     mfp na pf sh
  and   0  0  0  0
  bas   2  0  0  0
  ccs   0  0  1  0
  obs   0  0  1  0
  qzt   0  0  1  1
```

The problem isn't impossible to handle but does seem odd.

Comment: Please include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how R works without a reproducible example.

Comment: @Gung I think there is a statistical question here.  The O.P. has not asked how to do something in `R`, nor specifically *how* `R` works, but rather *why* it works as it does.  What would be the need to retain unused levels?  Why might that have been chosen as the default behavior?  These questions seem of general interest to me.  (And they do have answers based on database and reliable programming principles.)

Comment: For a reproducible example, here you are: